# How can I flush new object and execute DQL in the same transaction?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions

Can I flush new object (insert) and execute DQL (update some tables) in the same transaction with Doctrine? Or I have to use native SQL query with explicit transaction declaration?

I want to execute something like this in a transaction

```
INSERT INTO order VALUES (...)
UPDATE user SET email = :email, phone = :phone, status = :status
UPDATE user_counter SET order_counter = order_counter + 1
UPDATE some_counter SET acme_counter = acme_counter + 1
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: If this is what you do everytime then you could really use a stored procedure and just execute that from Symfony.

Comment: I have no exp with stored procedure and queries depend a lot of external conditions so I think I should not use stored procedure.
Should I use native SQL query in this situation?

Comment: I am not even sure how native SQL would help you in this situations. I don't know what conditions are there but they should be possible to take care of in stored procedures as well. You haven't mentioned what db you use. Try looking into stored procedures. It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Any info about that ? I would like to inject DELETE DQL statements into persist transactions `:|`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wrapInTransaction` function of the `entityManager`. You can mix persist/remove with other DQL queries.

Here's an example:

```
this->entityManager->wrapInTransaction(function ($em) use($phoneNumber, $phoneNumberVerificationRequest){
    $this->entityManager->persist($phoneNumber);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    $this->phoneNumberVerificationRequestRepository->removeByCountryCallingCodeAndNumber($phoneNumberVerificationRequest->getCountryCallingCode(), $phoneNumberVerificationRequest->getNumber());
});
```